# Last vs Previous/Earlier

Tags: word-usage, word-difference

When do we refer to **last** as **previous** or **earlier**? Does **last** stand instead of **previous** or **earlier** in the examples given below?

- **Last** time I saw you, you had black hair. (the previous time)
- Your **last** score was much better than your new one. (earlier or previous score)
- Over the **last** few years people have become more violent. (earlier years)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Last" in these contexts means "most recent" or "immediately-preceding".  Sometimes, of course, it can mean "final", but the context usually tells us whether that's the case.

"Previous" and "earlier" place the event in past time, but "earlier" does no sequencing at all and "previous" gives only a hint of sequence without help.

"[The] Last time I saw you..." is informal/conversational, but appropriate because such a comment would be very unlikely unless the people involved were friends, neighbors, or what's called "work friends".  To use "previous" or "earlier" would imply that there have only been 2 times, and this is the second.  Which, if true, would make such a personal comment a social error.

"Your last score..." can't be replaced in this case because here "last" means "most recent", "immediately-preceding", not just any "earlier" or "previous" one.  Again, using "earlier" or "previous" would imply that there've been only 2 scores.

"Over the last few years..." is the same sort of case as with the score:  "last few years" refers to the most recent few years, not just any earlier years.